# How to stop looper execution?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a looper thread that is running always and pull tasks from queue in order to execute them.

There is a main looper method

```
public void Start()
        {
            m_looperThread = new Thread(() =>
             {
                 while (true)
                 {
                    //Dequeue use lock inside
                    TASK_TYPE task = m_taskList.GetAndRemoveFirst();

                     if (task == null || !m_isThreadRunning)
                     {
                         break;
                     }

                     task.Execute();
                     FinishedTask(task);
                 }
             }
                )
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };

            m_looperThread.Start();
        }
```

Now if I need to close an application, user need to click red cross and before closing I need to abort all looper tasks.

How I do it

```
        public void Abort()
        {
            Put(default(TASK_TYPE));
            m_isThreadRunning = false;

            if (m_looperThread != null)
            {
                m_looperThread.Join();
            }

            m_taskList.Clear();
        }
```

So, first of all I put a null item and additional I set `m_isThreadRunning` value to false because in looper method I am checking this values in order to stop it. Then I call `.Join()` to make sure that I finished this thread and clear task list. Now I know exactly that all tasks were aborted, threads were joined and all is fine.

But issue here in this line

```
task.Execute();
```

What is the issue - when task run and user need to close the application I can't `.Join` the looper thread before task finish the job (it could be 1 minute). And finally it is looks like application in stuck.

So, question is - how correctly `.join` the thread and give to user opportunity to close the application?

Comment: check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Comment: You should implement some logic to [cancel the task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Comment: 1 minute tasks? You probably should make them cancellable as per @AhmedAbdelhameed comment or, if it's hard/not possible, you can just show some dialog "Closing software, please wait".